# Question about decimal separator

Tags: c#, xml, separator

Is decimal separator ('.' or ',' ) depends of `CurrentCulture`?

I have a problem in serialization `XML`.
When I type ',' as separator, I have an exception. (Culture is setted as DE-de)

Regards

example ( TestProperties is my own class for testing)

```
TestProperties properties = new TestProperties 

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);

double tempValue = 1.23 // Or 1,23
properties.DoubleValue = tempValue;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestProperties));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(XMLPath);
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, properties);
textWriter.Close();


public class TestProperties
    {   
        private double _doubleValue;
        [XmlElement("Double")]
        public double DoubleValue
        {
            get { return _doubleValue; }
            set { _doubleValue = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's culture specific, but it depends what you are doing. Can you show us the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends entirely on the context. You mention xml; *within xml*, the format is usually represented in a non-cultural culture (which means: . is decimal and , is thousands etc). Similarly, xml has specific representations for dates/times.

If you are building your xml via `XmlWriter`, `XElement`, `XmlSerializer` (etc) this will be automatic; if you are building it by hand it could well be confused (a mix of different representations).

If the data is *not* in the expected format, you might have to load it into a `string` property (rather than, say, a `float` etc), and process it separately.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
I have another question.
I'm using XMLSerializator.
Is it using InvariantCulture, or it using CurrentCulture?
If current, can I use Invariant?

I'm using systems with different cultures, so I fave troubles with valid serialize or deserialize beetwen these systems.

Comment: @ogrod87 it is *xml* - so invariant *plus* a few other things (i.e. the DateTime format is different etc); culture should not be an issue *at the point of (de)serialization* - but of course, whatever you do after that is subject to culture. Is there a specific issue you are seeing?

Comment: Yes. It happens when I'm trying serialize values with point or comma as decimal separator. Depends on culture, on XML i have different values. I want to normalize xml. No matter if I type value with comma or point, I want get in XML value with point.

Comment: @ogrod87 do you have an example of how you are trying to serialize this? otherwise I'm only guessing

Comment: @ogrod87 and with that example, what is the *desired* xml, and what is the *actual* (undesired) xml?

Comment: desire: always with dot
actual: depends of culture(sometimes dot, sometimes comma, sometimes 0)

Comment: @ogrod that sounds odd... Unexpected

Comment: yeah, I know. Maybe if i will not find a solution, I will create my own xml serializer. Of course based on .net xml serializer.

Answer (score 4):

Decimal separator is determined by the current culture, however, for XML Serialization, the current culture is not taken into account.  XML convention will have to be used; decimal separator in XML will always be a point.

If you're building the XML by hand, you should use the [`XMLConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx) class to make sure that all data-types are formatted correctly in the XML.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
I have another question.
I'm using XMLSerializator.
Is it using InvariantCulture, or it using CurrentCulture?
If current, can I use Invariant?

I'm using systems with different cultures, so I fave troubles with valid serialize or deserialize beetwen these systems.