# Displaying a Float to a Textbox type "number"

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, floating-point

There is a lot of questions regarding the conversion of a Textbox string to a float value, or allowing a Textbox of type="number" to allow decimal points, however, I can't seem to find anything related to displaying a float value to a Textbox with it's type set to "number".

So far, what I have is a Textbox with type="number" and step="0.01". It also has a min value of "0". It shows like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Number" step="0.01" Width="140px" min="0"></asp:TextBox>
```

It works fine for user input and saves the data to a varable/database without any problem. However, if I want to display this same value back to the user, it doesn't display anything, not even a "0".

So my question is: How can I take the value form a "float", convert it to a "string", and apply it to the Textbox.Text, so that it displays the value?

As an example: If I set the value in the Textbox as "5", it will save and display "5", but if I put "5.5" or "5,5", either way, it never displays it, and I need it to display "5.5".

Any ideas?

PS: It is supposed to represent a monetary value. I would also prefer to have a solution that doesn't require Javascript, if possible.

Comment: Your question answered a question I had about how to make the input accept the decimal number, and not force me into using an integer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A float 5.5 is not exactly a real value of 5.5 (see [.Net Float Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx))

I strongly suggest you to NEVER use floats for monetary values! It is best practice to use a decimal type for These things.

That said, if you really want to use floats, when you read the value from the DB do this:

```
TextBox1.Text = ((decimal)myNum.ToString( "0.##" )).Tostring()
```

With this solution you can leave the stepping as you whish "0.01"

P.S. As Tiago pointed out there can be a mismatch between your culture and the floating point separator. decimals expect dots but maybe your number has a comma. In this case convert like that:

```
decimal.Parse("18,285", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," })
```

[got it from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893407/string-to-decimal-conversion-dot-separation-instead-of-comma)

Comment: Ah, I see! Decimal would be the missing piece here. Is decimal translated to "Real" in SQL?

Comment: @TiagoCachinho no, SQL knows decimal as well. [SQL DECIMAL()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187746(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Ok, so I tested it, and it looks like it saves "better" in SQL, and the value is well used throughout the program, but it still isn't rendered in the textbox... Am I missing something? BTW, I tried with ToString("0.##") and straight up ToString() but it's the same. I also tried ToString("N2").

Comment: Another thing I tested, just in case, is to set the textbox to type="text", to test if the value is correctly displayed. In fact, the value is correct and it shows on the textbox, but it's still a type="text" and I need a type="number".

Answer (score 4):

set `any` value to [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) attribute.

```
 <input type="number" step="any"/>
```

You can use `Convert.ToSingle()` or `float.Parse` to convert string to float

```
var value = Convert.ToSingle(TextBox1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 //Or
 var value1 = float.Parse(TextBox1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And use `ToString("N")` of instance method to convert float to string.

```
var str = floatNum.ToString("N"); // or N2 (2 digit decimal)
```

Comment: Interesting. Does that meen that I can set the value "5.555555" in the textbox? I would prefer to have a limit to how many decimal cases I want to be able to input.

Comment: You have to use `JavaScript`.

Comment: I down-voted this because (as first answer by KarmaEDV said)... you really MUST (my emphasise) use Decimal type for money (or errors will result).

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some research on Textbox type number, I discovered that HTML5 input type="number" is a mess. I know it is not really interesting for some, but I know one or two programmers that will bump into the same problem.

@KarmaEDV has the best answer for the problem, as decimal type values are the correct way to process currency. However, @AVD was also right, where if you set it to "any" it will accept values of any size in decimal cases.

Meanwhile, it lead to another problem. When you set an input with the type number, that box will only receive values that are numerical or DOT (point). If you're not working with english notations, you might use "," (comma) as your decimal point. Crazy things happen here, where the box accepts "," and when the value is saves, it is still a valid decimal value, but when you convert the value (with the ","), it will create a string of character with ",". Ex.: the value 5,5 is in string "5,5" literally.

As the box those not accept ",", it won't render it. Solution?
    .ToString().Replace(',','.');
as simple as that.

Want more? It still displays "5,5" with the "," (comma)... There's the reason why it causes trouble...

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check in the code-behind using something like :

```
TextBox1.Text.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also use

```
float.TryParse( TextBox1.Text)
```

To see if the value is a float, or if you can treat it as a normal string.

Comment: This would apply to read the value from the Textbox, however, I want to write it to the Textbox. But thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Probable best practice is to forget Text="Number" (due to problems specified above) and validate user input using Decimal.TryParse().  For US currency, I also suggest making sure there are no more than two digits after the decimal point and (better) to make sure that there are EXACTLY two digits to the right of decimal point to catch possible entry errors (if only 1 digit to right of decimal point could be unintended).