# Issue with parsing and multiplying by 1000 in order to get ms instead of seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, int, decimal

I'm having an issue after submitting a form with the following error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

My code:

```
  Decimal intervalStart = Decimal.Parse(IntervalTime.Text);
  Decimal intervalTotal = intervalStart * 1000;
  string interval = intervalTotal.ToString();
```

I am trying to get a total in whole number rather than decimal, but the decimal is crucial in order to get that whole number (when multiplied by 1000).
For example, my small application reads a video file and puts the total in seconds in the "IntervalTime.Text" box. This is then converted into milliseconds and becomes a whole number.

> Video: 87.524 seconds. Multiply it by 1000, you get 87524. <- This is what I need but continue getting the above error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to me like you're not actually inputting a valid `decimal` value in your textbox.

Comment: You could try to use `float` (or `Single`) instead of `decimal`.

Comment: Share the value of `IntervalTime.Text` please.

Comment: I just posted an image of it on the thread. Thank you.

Comment: What's the decimal separator on your OS?

Comment: It is a '.' and not a ','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
string b = "87.524";
Decimal intervalStart2 = Decimal.Parse(a);
```

But this does:

```
string a = "87,524";
Decimal intervalStart1 = Decimal.Parse(a);
```

Problem is in **delimiter**.

One of possible **solutions** could be:

```
string b = "87.524";
b = b.Replace(".", ",");
Decimal intervalStart = Decimal.Parse(b);
```

Also in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137007/displaying-a-float-to-a-textbox-type-number) it is shown how to define delimiter yourself:

```
decimal.Parse("87.524", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." })
```

Another way is to define specific `CultureInfo`:

```
decimal.Parse("87.524", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Thank you, the last two solutions you provided helped solve the issue. I will post the final code/answer in my original post above. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

The `Decimal.Parse(String)` parse the number which is in this format:

*[ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws]*

Be carefull that

1. **,** is a culture-specific thousands separator symbol.
2. **.** is a culture-specific decimal point symbol

This means that both 87,524 and 87.524 could be valid decimal number strings depending on the system culture.