# How to Convert a Negative String to Decimal value?

Tags: c#

Im trying to convert a negative string like `"-23.27"` to a decimal point value, And the problem is sometimes im getting negative values inside parenthesis like `"(23.27)"`.

I have written the code to control parenthesis And get the decimal point value in negative format, but when the same code is running with `"-23.27"` it returns a Input string was not in a correct format Error. This is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
decimal ValueN = (decimal.Parse("-23.27", 
                  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowParentheses | 
                  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | 
                  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | 
                  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands));
```

Comment: _NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowParentheses_

Comment: You forgot a couple (leading sign and decimal).  Just use Number | AllowParentheses.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're missing the `AllowLeadingSign` flag

```
decimal ValueN= (decimal.Parse("-23.27",  
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowParentheses |  
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | 
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | 
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands | 
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint |
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign));
```

Comment: It worked. i dont know how i missed that. Thank you so much

Comment: As a side-note, I needed `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` when parsing `-23.27`, else I got an exception.

Comment: Good catch, let me add it in.