# Convert a negative string decimal value to double in c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert a value in string format like `-14.3` to double.

I am currently using `Convert.ToDouble()` to convert positive values to double but in case of negative decimal values it returns unexpected results. For `-14.3` it returns `-143`. So need some help in this regard

```
 private double getDouble(string Value)
        {
            double result = 0;
            try
            {               
                result = Convert.ToDouble(Value);                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = 0;
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I doubt this is because of using negative values but because the comma-seperator. In your current culture there´s obviously another seperator that indicates where the int-part starts and where the decimals end. To check this also check for positive `14.3`. which should also go to `143`.

Comment: Your code would help a lot.

Comment: take a look at this reference please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277684/how-to-convert-a-negative-string-to-decimal-value

Comment: Use `Convert.ToDouble("-14.3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Seems to a problem with current culture of my system.Also Convert.ToDouble("-14.3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) this doesn't work..

Comment: I have to make it work for client in Istanbul....

Comment: What does `Convert.ToDouble("-14.3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` give you? If it's not `-14.3` you have a really weird problem...

Comment: Sorry @MatthewWatson!! some rubbish code added previously was not allowing your solution to work! Its working fine.Thanks a lot..........

Comment: This question and the comments saved me. My unit tests  run in multiple cultures and it was throwing off the parser from an unrelated test. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `NumberFormatInfo` to specify the characters used for the negative sign and the decimal separator.

```
var format = new NumberFormatInfo();
format.NegativeSign = "-";
format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

var negativeNumber = Double.Parse("-14.3", format); // -14.3
var positiveNumber = Double.Parse("352.6", format); // 352.6
```

[See the code in action on repl.it](https://repl.it/GtmT/2).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Double.TryParse` with `NumberFormatInfo`you need to specify `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` and `NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign`.

```
var format = new NumberFormatInfo();
format.NegativeSign = "-";
format.NumberNegativePattern = 1;
format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

double negativeNumber;
Double.TryParse("-14.3", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format, out negativeNumber); // -14.3
double positiveNumber;
Double.TryParse("352.6", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, format, out positiveNumber); // 352.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Convert.ToDouble function, use:

```
public static double mtdGetDouble(string Value)
{
    if (Value == "" || Value == "-") return 0;
    else return Convert.ToDouble(Value);
}
```

(It's my Style...)