# Why does "decimal.TryParse()" always return 0 for the input string "-1" in the below code?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

The below code should return the -1 decimal value but it's returning 0. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
decimal validity = -1;
validityStr = "-1";

decimal.TryParse(validityStr, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out validity);
```

**Expected Output:**

> -1

**Actual Output:**

> 0

Comment: I assume that the method is returning `false`?

Comment: I think you might need to include `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign`.  Take a look at this _similar_ question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277684/how-to-convert-a-negative-string-to-decimal-value

Comment: It's poor practice to call a `Try` method and then ignore if it returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You forgot to tell TryParse that the leading sign is OK

```
decimal validity = -1;
var validityStr = "-1";

decimal.TryParse(validityStr, 
    NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    out validity);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use `NumberStyles.Float`, `NumberStyles.Number` or one of the already set up composite values in that enum, simpler than having to specify all of the `Allow[blank]` lines individually.

Comment: Why isn't `AllowLeadingSign` a default behaviour? Call it a failure of the imagination, but I honestly can't imagine a situation in which I would want to opt out of it.

Comment: @Alexander you aren't required to specfy a `NumberStyles`. If you don't use this overload of `TryParse`, the default includes `AllowLeadingSign`. As `NumberStyles` is a flags enum, it is additive. A `DisallowLeadingSign` value would be a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: Yes, in fact you could just use `decimal.TryParse(validityStr, out validity);` and not even bother with the `NumberStyles` or `CultureInfo`.  That will work in the vast majority of cases, but you might need to be more specific if you're localizing the project to places with different number formats.

Comment: @Alexander There are a number of circumstances where a -ve value might not be valid (prices for example). The whole point of these flags is to allow you to be as specific as you need to be over what is or isn't valid.

Comment: @SteveTodd Eh, it's still a valid `decimal` to be parsed. It might be an invalid value in your business domain, but that should be up to your business layer, not the parsing layer. (i.e. parse value normally, even if it's negative, then check if it's negative, too big, too small, whatever, as a second step)

Comment: @Alexander To put the answer to your first comment another way, `NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign` _is_ the "default" (it's included/enabled) if you specify `NumberStyles.Any`, `NumberStyles.Float`, `NumberStyles.Integer`, or `NumberStyles.Number`.  If you don't use one of those composite values and instead use the `NumberStyles.Allow*` values, as in the question, you're effectively saying "I'm going to pick exactly what I want", so be prepared to have to explicitly include _every_ value you want.  That is, you don't get the defaults _when you opt out of the defaults_.

Answer (score 6):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__):

> When this method returns, contains the Decimal number that is equivalent to the numeric value contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or **zero if the conversion failed**. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or Empty, is not a number in a valid format, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. This parameter is passed uininitialized; any value originally supplied in result is overwritten.

Since the conversion failed, validity becomes 0. To make sure the conversion works you should add [NumberStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.8).AllowLeadingSign