# Double in SQLite with C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, double

I want to save a double into my SQLite DB with C# and read it out again.

Now the problem:

**At first the input:**

If i save a double with a point ( e.g `20.50` ) an insert it in my database i get `2050.0`.

If i save it with a comma ( e.g `20,30` ) i get in my db `20,3`. That what i want.

**Code Input:**

```
String sql = $"INSERT INTO tablename (number) VALUES ('{number}')";                         

SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = " + nameDB + ".sqlite; Version = 3;");
dbConnection.Open();
SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnection);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Command.Parameters.Clear();
dbConnection.Close();
```

number is a double in c# and in sqllite REAL

**But now the output:**

If in my db is the value 20,3 and i read it out with:

```
double number = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("tablename"));
```

> Error: InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

or

```
decimal number = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("tablename"));
```

> Error: wrong inputformat

If i use the reader without the get-methods i get the number without decimals after the comma like int.

Both works if the format in the db is with a point instead of a comma. But this doesnt work for the input.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide an [mcve] of how you are inserting into the database. Please also share the data types (in the DB) of each of the columns.

Comment: Why are you storing a number in a string in the database?

Comment: @mjwills worked first time with sqllite db and found this solution to store data

Comment: If you are storing the number in a string in the database (which is extremely bad practice) - then this appears to be a localisation issue. Try reading the value as a string & parsing the string to double or decimal specifying the decimal separator as comma - see bottom answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893407/string-to-decimal-conversion-dot-separation-instead-of-comma